# How to ignore redirection in joomla user login module

Tags: ajax, authentication, joomla

Am triggering the user login method through Ajax and need a successful logged in message instead of URL redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla use login method from UsersControllerUser controller if you try to login in default way.

This method automatically redirect you after login,if you don't want to you can modifiy this method by adding parameter or create a new one.

In all case the login process should pass through app->login() method that will do all the process for you and return true in case of success.